# IndexedDB throws an error when adding a new value into database

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb

I created a database in [IndexedDb](https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb) successfully but when I try to add a value into the database, I see the following error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating
>   the object store's key path did not yield a value.

Code snippet:

```
let db = new AngularIndexedDB('myDb', 1);

db.createStore(1, (evt) => {
  const objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore('people', { keyPath: 'id', unique: true });
    objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
    objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });
  }).then(() => {
    db.add('people', { name: 'name', email: 'email' }).then(() => {
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

}, (error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

I checked the name of table. That is exactly the same. As well its value respective their keys.

How can I resolve this issue ? Could you please share insight on this error ?

Your help would highly appreciate . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an object store with a key path:

```
 const store = db.createObjectStore('people', { keyPath: 'id' });
```

Then either:

1. You must also specify that the store should use a key generator, i.e. `{keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true}`, which will cause numeric keys to be generated for you (1, 2, 3, ...) and injected into the values; or:
2. The values you store must already include a property matching the keypath, e.g. `store.put({name: 'foo', id: 1234})`

(Also, `unique` is not a property of object stores, only indexes. Keys are always unique within object stores.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error when tried to force IndexDB to create a copy of a record in the database by saving a deep copy of the record in which the key was assigned an 'undefined'.
Apparently the trick was to delete the property from the object:

```
 const record: T = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r));
 r.key = undefined; // does not work!
 delete(r.key); // works! with autoincrement it forces IndexDB to create a new key
 await datastore.add(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing a similar problem with TypeScript properties.

Presume we have this model

```
export default class Model {
   private _id: number;
   public get id(){
      return this._id;
   }
   public set id(value: number){
      this._id = value;
   }
}
```

Let's init the objectStore like this

```
   db.createObjectStore('Models', {
                        keyPath: 'id'
                    });
```

And then we want to save our Model

```
   let model = new Model();
   let ts = db.transaction('Models', "readwrite");
   let store = ts.objectStore('Models');
   store.add(model);
```

Unfortunately we will receive a

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.
```

That's because as now IndexedDB has problems to interpret our transpiled Model (I don't know why, can it probably be related to tsconfig.json?)

Once we change our model to

```
   export default class Model {
      public id: number;
   }
```

And then try to save it, we will achieve a successfully completed transaction.